# IQ test question - squares, triangles, dots

Tags: pattern, visual, progressive-matrix

I have this question from a friend. We have no idea where to start. What is the correct answer and reasoning?

[image: question-image]

Source: "Ghid de pregătire pentru concursul de directori/ directori adjuncți din învățământul preuniversitar", Gabriel Vrânceanu, Gabriela Bărbulescu,... Editura Scrib, București, 2016